# Groovy Array.addAll method remove the elements from original array

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

Ok I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.

```
result = []
for (aMp in arMap)  {
    println("0 " + result)
    println("1 " + aMp)
    println("2 " + delegate.findSingleMap(aMp))
    result.addAll(delegate.findSingleMap(aMp))
    println "3 " + result
}
return result
```

The println result are the following: (I have 2 element in arMap, so it print the four value 2 times)

```
0 []
1 [ID:XXX, Type:4]
2 [[First:21/Nov/2013,  Type:4, error code:SXR07, ID:XXX, Test ID:5]]
3 [[First:21/Nov/2013,  Type:4, error code:SXR07, ID:XXX, Test ID:5]]
0 [[First:21/Nov/2013,  Type:4, error code:SXR07, ID:XXX, Test ID:5]]
1 [ID:YYY, Type:4]
2 [[First:12/Oct/2012,  Type:4, error code:SXR07, ID:YYY, Test ID:6]]
3 [[First:12/Oct/2012,  Type:4, error code:SXR07, ID:YYY, Test ID:6]]
```

As you can see the findSingleMap function work properly, but the second time I use the AddAll, my result array loose the value XXX.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You post not all you code. Where string that starts from 0 come from?

Comment: @talex just added. I was wondering if the result reset before the beginning of next cycle and I added a print

Comment: does your `findSingleMap` also work with a variable `result`?  Using a simplified version of your code works fine for me (groovy 2.2.1) and `addAll` works as advertised.

Comment: @cfrick You got it right. Want to turn it into an answer? My findSingleMap was  result = delegate
for (aEl in map) {
result = result.findAll({ it[aEl.key] == aEl.value })
}     
return result

Comment: @cfrick I'm still quite young in groovy scripting and I'm loosing sight of scope of variable all the time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the OP int the comments the method `findSingleMap` modifies the (global) `result` variable.

```
for (aEl in map) { 
    result = result.findAll { it[aEl.key] == aEl.value } 
}

return result
```

Not writing `def` in front a variable declares it (in simple scripts) global, which might result in strange behaviour like this.  So don't do it, unless you have to codegolf.